# How does WPF determine that something should be redrawn? How do I find out?

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl

Well, that goes quite deep into WPFish foundations but see:

Short: How to implement my own RenderThread.

I am working on a problem where I need 10Bit display inside a WPF application. For this and for other reasons it must be OpenGL (which is well capable to do 10Bit). Bindings and WPF controls are well known and their features beloved gby us. So for the few Controls, I hope to use them and maybe even draw them within my OpenGL-context.

Interestingly I got some parts of WPF working as independent Object tree using my own `PresentationSource`. Layout works, however Events do currently fail due to missing parts (Focus). Probably events never work because it is not possible to derive from some internal classes like `CompositionTarget` ... :-/

BUT:

So I can do my own drawing in my OpenGL-context (just a copuple of buttons and borders) but I can't get the Idea out of my mind to inspect the WPF Visual-Tree, grab all the `DrawingGroups` and redo the painting in OpenGL.

What I get is a tree of `DrawingGroups`, `EllipseGeometry` and `RectangleGeometry` - so drawable primitives.

```
    DrawingGroup drawing = VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing((Visual) firstChild);
```

The problem with that idea is: How do I determine if the / my visual tree has changed. And I mean not the whole but a dependency property on there. Explain: There is a WPF override `protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)` but as of my observation it is not called often enough. What I want to observe is: When an Animation takes place, it animates for example Width or Opacity or Brushes which are part of the Visual-Tree. I need to redraw my OpenGL-context, then. How does WPF determine and how do I observe that?

Comment: Just my opinion but it seems like you're using the wrong tool for the job here.

Answer (score 2):

I think [LayoutUpdated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should give you what you need.

Consider this code sample:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="525" Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
    <StackPanel>
        <Canvas x:Name="TargetCanvas"  Height="300">
            <Rectangle x:Name="Subject" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="50" Fill="Maroon" Height="25" Width="25"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Button Content="Move">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard Target="{Binding ElementName=Subject}" TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" AutoReverse="True">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="200" Duration="00:00:02"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TargetCanvas.LayoutUpdated += TargetCanvas_LayoutUpdated;
    }

    void TargetCanvas_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + ": Layout updated\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: An animation targeting a RenderTransform (such as TranslateTransform) won't impact the layout, and therefore won't trigger the LayoutUpdated event

Comment: True, though I did get some results when I tried adding a RenderTransform (though admittedly, they weren't as good as without the transform). But he talked about opacity and brushes, that don't need transforms to be animated.

Comment: Your are both right. Thanks foremost.
The event triggers on layout changes but other important changes like colors or so do not trigger. So I am fighting with myself if I should mark it as answer or not....